# Is it a good idea to encode a audio & video file in base64 string & then send it to the other user in android using xmpp

Tags: android, xmpp

Is it a good idea to encode a audio & video file in base64 string & then send it to the other user in android using xmpp

Below is the code I am using to send images

```
file = new File("/storage/emulated/0/download1index.jpg");

try {          
    // Reading a Image file from file system
    FileInputStream imageInFile = new FileInputStream(file);
    byte imageData[] = new byte[(int) file.length()];
    imageInFile.read(imageData);

    // Converting Image byte array into Base64 String
    String imageDataString = encodeImage(imageData);

    // Converting a Base64 String into Image byte array
    byte[] imageByteArray = decodeImage(imageDataString);

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageByteArray, 0, imageByteArray.length);
    ivImg.setImageBitmap(bitmap);


public static String encodeImage(byte[] imageByteArray){
    // return Base64.encodeToString(imageByteArray, 1);
    return StringUtils.encodeBase64(imageByteArray);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this file transfer method called [In-Band Bytestreams](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0047.html) and if you wrap your base64 data in XML packets defined in this XMPP extension - you can transfer files not only to your app, but to many other XMPP clients.

Major disadvantages of in-band file transfer is:

- base64 encoding increases file size up to 30%
- XMPP servers usually have limits on XML packet size, you should split file into small chunks that fit into limits, and send with delay to fit in XMPP server's traffic shaper limits. File transfer speed is too low in this case.

Comment: thanks, but is there any way to compress the size of the string before sending the file or is there any alternative method to send audio & video file